# Jquery check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a parent div which hold a check box what i would like to achieve is check or uncheck the wherever I click in the parent div or directly on the check box.

```
$('.select').click(function(){
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')){
        checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lt2Hw/2/

The problem is that if you click directly on the check box it dos not check :(

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because event propagation.

When you click on the checkbox first the checkbox changes its state, then the event is propagated to the the parent elements thus reaching the `.select` element where the state is again reversed to so it gets back to the state before the click

Try

```
$('.select').click(function (e) {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    if (checkbox.is(e.target)) {
        return;
    }

    checkbox.prop('checked', function (i, checked) {
        return !checked;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/99daw/)

---

Or prevent the propagation of the click event from the checkbox

```
$('.select').click(function (e) {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
    checkbox.prop('checked', function (i, checked) {
        return !checked;
    });
});
$('.select input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZCngE/)

Comment: Thank You! I was searching for day's.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Lt2Hw/3/)</kbd>

Use [event.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Stop Propagation on Checkbox click event.

```
$('.select input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

**Problem**

When you click on checkbox the parent is also clicked so event fires when changes it's state again .

Check this demo to understand the problem

<kbd>[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Lt2Hw/4/)</kbd>